# Login with fb integration in laravel 5.2

Tags: php

Is it possible to integrate login with facebook using laravel5.2? because i tried many tutorials but non of them seems working, but when I tried the tutorial that is using a laravel 5.3, it worked.

Comment: Use [Socialite 2.0](https://github.com/laravel/socialite/tree/2.0)

Comment: Will traditional login and login with facebook can be integrated together too?

Comment: Yes you can handle it in your `LoginController`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin for Laravel : https://github.com/laravel/socialite

Comment: Also mention about version, 3.0 is for laravel 5.3 and above as he is using laravel 5.2 so socialite 2.0 will work

Comment: Thank you very much for your response , very much appreciated, I will try it sir.